# How can I include html with ember-cli only for a specific environment?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In my `Brocfile.js` I'm importing a script:

```
// Import script for development only
if (app.env === 'development') {
  app.import( app.bowerDirectory + '/some-script/some-script.js' );
};
```

That works just fine. But I also need to include a small init script in the html (which isn't really a vendor asset) which should not be included in a production build. How do I include some html only for a specific environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still check your config file from any file in your project:

```
import config from '../path/to/config/environment';

if(config.environment === "development") {
  someScript.init();
}
```

Comment: So where would you include this? Because it seems to me that this solution would still render out into the production build (it just would never be activated). I'd prefer it if I can keep this out of production entirely. Or is that impossible?

Comment: if you want to keep it out entirely you'll need to put it in a separate file and add it with `app.import`. why do you need it out entirely?

Comment: Because it does some linting in the browser (html-inspector), which doesn't really make sense for production builds. I assume the init script should go in `vendor` right?